# How to display OpenStreetMap in python kivy gui?

Tags: python, leaflet, kivy, openstreetmap, polyline

as you can see from the title, i want to know how i can display an OSM map in python kivy gui?
In addition, i want to know how to create a polylines in OSM that can diaplay me a bus route for exapmle? 
(Assuming I have a file that includes all the coordinates of the route)
Thank you.

Comment: Use MapView from the kivy garden which pulls from OpenStreet Maps. I have had success with this on desktop and iOS: https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.mapview

Comment: i cant understanf how to use Kivy-garden, can you help me please?

Comment: what do i need to write in CMD before "garden install mapview"?

Comment: Probably you're missing the `pip install kivy-garden` line. More instructions about the garden project: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.garden.html Once you have finished `pip install kivy-garden` you should be able to do `garden install mapview` and access it. To include a garden module in a mobile app, you need to run `garden install --app mapview` while in the folder of your project on your computer.